# Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an AppleScript that will toggle Bluetooth, but I can't seem to get past the following error:

```
Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”.
```

Here's my code:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
reveal pane id "com.apple.preferences.Bluetooth"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    set bluetooth to checkbox "On" of window 1
    set bluetoothBool to value of checkbox "On" of window 1 as boolean
    tell bluetooth
        if bluetoothBool = false then
            click bluetooth
            display dialog "Bluetooth on" with title "Bluetooth"
                buttons "OK" "Turn Bluetooth off"
                default button "OK"
        else if bluetoothBool = true then
            click bluetooth
            display dialog "Bluetooth off" with title "Bluetooth"
                buttons "OK" "Turn Bluetooth on"
                default button "OK"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit
```

end tell

Comment: Does it say which line the error is on?

Comment: Nope, the basic AppleScript compiler is pretty useless. But user andrew solved my problem in the below answer.

Answer (score 4):

`"OK" "Turn Bluetooth off"` needs to be `{"OK", "Turn Bluetooth off"}`.

Also, `display dialog` statements need to go all on one line, unless you "continue” a line with `¬`, entered by typing Option-l (lowercase L).

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preferences.Bluetooth"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
        set bluetooth to checkbox "On" of window 1
        set bluetoothBool to value of checkbox "On" of window 1 as boolean
        tell bluetooth
            if bluetoothBool = false then
                click bluetooth
                display dialog "Bluetooth on" with title ¬
                    "Bluetooth" buttons {"OK", "Turn Bluetooth off"} ¬
                    default button "OK"
            else if bluetoothBool = true then
                click bluetooth
                display dialog "Bluetooth off" with title ¬
                    "Bluetooth" buttons {"OK", "Turn Bluetooth on"} ¬
                    default button "OK"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

Source: [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/AppleScriptLanguageGuide.pdf)

Comment: OPTION-RETURN does also the  ¬ - thingy

Comment: I discovered quitting and reopening Apple Script Editor worked after initially finding the answer did not work.